# how do i unload view controllers ? or a least make it run viewDidAppear each time?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisplitviewcontroller, childviewcontroller

i want to "unload" view controllers so they get read each time a user click on them in the uitableview
it's a uisplitviewcontroller with childviewcontrollers
how is this possible ?

```
-(void)Graviditeten:(int)viewId {
UIViewController *viewController;
switch (viewId) {
    case 0:
        viewController = self.jegKomTil;
        break;
    case 1:
        viewController = self.scannet1;
        break;
    case 2:
        viewController = self.ugeForUge;
        break;
    case 3:
        viewController = self.opfoeselIMave;
        break;
    case 4:
        viewController = self.specielleMinderGravid;
        break;
    case 5:
        viewController = self.nakkefold;
        break;
    case 6:
        viewController = self.mdScan;
        break;
    case 7:
        viewController = self.madMorHave;
        break;
    case 8:
        viewController = self.tingFar;
        break;
}
[self showChildViewController:viewController];
}


-(void)showChildViewController:(UIViewController*)content {
if(topController != content) {
    content.view.frame = [self.view frame];
    [self.view addSubview:content.view];
    [content dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    [content didMoveToParentViewController:self];
    [self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

    topController = content;
}
}
```

so far i tried this in the `ShowChildViewController`

```
[content dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

but then it shows nothing

Comment: You shouldn't be trying to dismiss a controller if you didn't present it in the first place. It looks like you're trying to add controllers as children with your showChildViewController method (you're missing the line, [self addChildViewController:content]). Is the code you posted in a container view controller?

Comment: @rdelmar yes it's posted in my container view controller

Comment: @rdelmar if i write that code you wrote, i get this when ever i change user  *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'

Comment: @rdelmar hmm my content becomes nil for some reason when i move down the uitableview-> another uitableview

Comment: Hard to say what's happening without knowing more about your overall controller hierarchy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
-(void)showChildViewController:(UIViewController*)content {
if(topController != content) {
    content.view.frame = [self.view frame];
    [content.view removeFromSuperview];
    [self.view addSubview:content.view];
    [content.view setNeedsDisplay];
    [content didMoveToParentViewController:self];

    topController = content;
}
}
```

This works!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you don't really want to unload the vc's view, but rather to refresh when it's about to be presented.  The `UISplitViewControllerDelegate` gets notified with `splitViewController:willShowViewController:invalidatingBarButtonItem` before a vc is shown.  The vc being shown is a parameter.  See doc [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISplitViewControllerDelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UISplitViewControllerDelegate/splitViewController%3awillShowViewController%3ainvalidatingBarButtonItem%3a).

Comment: i don't quite understand what you wrote. but yes i want to refresh the vc if possible. the - (void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)svc willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)aViewController invalidatingBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)button
 what do i put in it ? beside a button function  ?

Comment: You can assign a delegate to the SVC.  It can be any object that implements the protocol.  A common choice is to have the first vc be the delegate.

Comment: what's IB ?
i'm using storyboards ?!?!